# JavaFX binding in initialize method

Tags: javafx

I am trying to create a binding to provide a button a way to disable/enable itself whenever a listview contains items or not. However, I don't get it to work.
This is my initialize method

```
private void initialize(){
    runButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(listView.getItems());
}
```

Adding items to the listView has no effects whatsoever on the disabled/enabled state of the button.

If I put the above line of code in another random function that is called later on in the program, it works.

I've read that the bindings might be garbage collected so I've also tried to create a field of the binding to then apply to the disabledProperty. This does not work either.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
listView.setItems(observableFiles)
```

is used to populate the list

Comment: Do you add `@FXML` annotation to your `initialize` metod in your code ? By degugging it, are you sure this binding is called at your window openning ?

Comment: Yes the binding is called before window opening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you call `listView.setItems()` anywhere in the code? If so that will explain why it doesn't work when you put it in `initialize` because you're binding to the old list object whereas the `ListView` is using the new list object.

Edit: Just seen your edit, it seems you really did this. Try calling the bindings after you call `setItems`.

Comment: OP may also want to observe the `ListView`'s `items` property to rebind as necessary, depending on if `setItems` will be called again at some point.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize listView.setItems() swapped the whole backing list.
I solved it by getting the original list that backed the listView and then just added/removed items from that one. This way I never have to call listView.setItems() at all.

Answer (score 0):

As another alternative you could add listener to *ListView* *itemsProperty* and if the changed list is empty trigger disable on your runButton.